# Update all rows in all tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a field (clientID) that repeats in most my tables (what is about 100 or so) and I am trying to update it all at once using oracle 11g. I was able to get the name of the tables but I am not able to use it. From the code below:

```
BEGIN
   FOR Name IN ( SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYS.all_tables where TABLESPACE_NAME='MyTableSpace') LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Name.TABLE_NAME); --I can't see any logs on DBMS Output for some reason
        -- Update Name.TABLE_NAME set ClientID = 1 Where ClientID = 2; --This line does not work message "Table or view does not exist"
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using dynamic SQL using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Something like this:

```
BEGIN
   FOR Name IN ( SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYS.all_tables where TABLESPACE_NAME='MyTableSpace') LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Name.TABLE_NAME); --I can't see any logs on DBMS Output for some reason
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update ' || Name.TABLE_NAME || ' set ClientID = 1 Where ClientID = 2';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

If you need to set the values to be updated dynamically, there are ways of binding the parameters with dynamic sql.  I just don't remember off-hand how to do it.  But if you need that, just ask in the comments, and I'll look for it.

**EDIT**

I think if you were to bind the values, it would look something like this:

```
BEGIN
   FOR Name IN ( SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYS.all_tables where TABLESPACE_NAME='MyTableSpace') LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Name.TABLE_NAME); --I can't see any logs on DBMS Output for some reason
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update ' || Name.TABLE_NAME || ' set ClientID = :1 Where ClientID = :2'
                          USING 1, 2;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

... where instead of `USING 1, 2`, you can use variables instead of hardcoding constant values.

For more information: [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317).

**EDIT 2**

If you need to skip tables that don't have the column in question, here is the adjusted query that should do the job:

```
BEGIN
   FOR Name IN (
     SELECT t.TABLE_NAME 
     FROM all_tables t
     where t.TABLESPACE_NAME='MyTableSpace'
     and exists (
       select null
       from all_tab_columns c
       where c.table_name = t.table_name
       and c.column_name = 'CLIENTID' -- put the right column name here
     )
   ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Name.TABLE_NAME); --I can't see any logs on DBMS Output for some reason
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update ' || Name.TABLE_NAME || ' set ClientID = 1 Where ClientID = 2';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

You may have to tweak it slightly, as I don't have an Oracle database in front of me.  I may have misspelled a few things.

Comment: Hi @sstan it almost work, I have very few tables that does not have the field and it crash the process, I may need to find a way to check it the field exist in the table before execute the sql

Comment: it did not work, the expression returns nil, and it is very strange, even if a run select * from all_tab_columns c where c.column_name = 'ClientID' I get an empty result

Comment: Did you try `CLIENTID` all upper case?  By default, Oracle stores all the column names in upper case.  Alternatively, just do a `SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'pick a table name here'`, and check what Oracle thinks the column name is.  It sounds like you're really close, you just need to figure out how to query the column metadata.

Comment: Yes thanks that was the problem I should had used all capitals now it is working, the variables did not work in the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but I hard code it and then it worked fine (maybe you want to edit the answer. Thanks again!